# iOS crash at CFAllocatedReferenceCountedObject

Tags: ios

My app frequently crashes with the following information:

```html
0 CFNetwork CFAllocatedReferenceCountedObject::_retainable_hash(void const*)
1 CoreFoundation    _CFBasicHashFindBucket + 164
2 CoreFoundation    CFDictionaryGetValue + 224
3 CFNetwork TubeManager::_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocol(MetaConnectionCacheClient*, HTTPRequestMessage const*, MetaConnectionOptions, BaseAwaitingTube*) + 80
4 CFNetwork TubeManager::_onqueue_reenqueueAwaitingTube(BaseAwaitingTube*) + 112
5 CFNetwork ___ZN11TubeManager21_onqueue_newTubeReadyEP4Tube13CFStreamError_block_invoke + 28
6 CFNetwork ___ZNK18QCoreSchedulingSet12performAsyncEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 52
7 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_client_callout + 16
9 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
10 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
11 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
12 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
13 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404
14 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 932
```

The crash device informations:
[image]

Who know how could this happen and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Interesting. I am seeing the same. I started to see these increase significantly after 2nd December 2017. increasing slowly for the first 5 or 6 days, and then more pronounced afterwards. Not sure if this is iOS 11.2 released, or another change in my app as I have done some updates too. When did you start to see this? Can you see a trend from a date? Do you use Facebook Audience Network or MoPub? Both of those frameworks have been updated in mine around the same time.

Comment: So, after more investigation, I am seeing a very similar trend line in increase of this issue starting at the point of iOS 11.2, and slowly increasing, but growing faster from the release of iOS 11.2.1. The trend lines seem rather similar. I will be interested to hear your findings.

Comment: @MrNeilM i started to see these increase significantly adter August 2017，and the iOS version from 10.3.3 to 11.2，i have not use those framekworks which you talk about，i use uiwebview in my app，i sespect the high version of ios can not work very well with uiwebview

Comment: @MrNeilM if use have found the reason and solve the problem，please tell me，thank u.

Comment: I have seen a few prior to the latest updates and it got a whole lot worse over this month though. Interesting that whilst you don't use those frameworks, you do use uiwebview, as the one thing in common in the crashlogs is javascript! And adverts use web views. I haven't yet got a fix, but will let you know if I find one!

Comment: Seeing this after 3th December 2017, looks like some issue in iOS... do you use AFNetworking?

Comment: i do user AFNetworking,but i think it has nothing to do with AFNetworking,all the document i got from internet show that maybe it's something wrong with  NSURLConnection，but AFNetworking is base on NSURLSession.i have replace UIWebView with WKWebViewin my lastest app version,now it crash more less(there is still a SDK also contain UIWebView which i can't replace it),so i guest  the high version of ios can not work very well with uiwebview.

Comment: To me 1. It's always happening in BG threads. 2. It happens when app is entering foreground (_sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks,  UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, etc). 3. iOS 11

Comment: maybe try out [Malloc Debug](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be coming from the network connection part.
Please check the code part related to network connection.

In my case, it occurred when I called the connection API repeatedly to the net in the background.
In other word, I called the network Api again before one Api is finished.
Or Before one api call is not completed, I moved to other screen(ViewController) that calls new Api.